# Origin of 3 types of elementary plaquette excitations in Majorana plaquette model

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, superconductivity, lattice-model

I'm studying [Majorana Fermion Surface Code for Universal Quantum Computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01724) by
Sagar Vijay, Timothy H. Hsieh, and Liang Fu. There they consider the Majorana plaquette model on an hexagonal lattice.

There are Majorana fermions ($\gamma_n$) at each lattice site and the Hamiltonian is $$H=-u\sum_p \mathcal{O}_p,$$ where $u>0$, $\mathcal{O}_p =i \Pi_{n\in vertex(p)}\gamma_n$ and $p$ denotes a labeling of the hexagonal plaquettes in the lattice.

The ground state of the system $|gs>$, satisfies $\mathcal{O}_p|gs>$ for all $p$.

Putting the system in a tours,the total fermion parity operator, $\Gamma$, is considered as $$ \Gamma= i^{\frac{N}{2}} \Pi_n \gamma_n,$$ where the lattice in the torus has $N$ sites.

It is asserted that "For convenience, we choose a unit cell for the honeycomb
lattice consisting of three plaquettes labeled A, B, and  C". The the fermion parity, on the torus, is equal to the product of Majorana fermions over the plaquettes of type A only, and algo equal to the producto over the other types separately.

Then it is discussed the way to excite the lattice above ground state, the need for string operators, etc. In this context my question is: ¿how is it  the excistence of three types of excitations, A,B,C, deduced from the above considerations? I see it is related to the 3-coloring of the lattice and to the conservation of $\Gamma$ and also to the possibility of expressing it only considering separate colors so these restrictions limit the types of excitations above ground state (that change the eigenvalue of one or more $\mathcal{O}_p$ operators) but I can understand the complete argument.

I understand that if I change the eigenvalues of two diferent color plaquettes, I ruin the fermion parity so this is not allowed. Via the same token I won't be able to change one type of excitation (say a red plaquette excited) into another (say green) because this would violate fermion parity conservation.

I can't see why the *three coloring* (topology) implies three diferent *physical* excitations, what distinguishes them physicall? is it related to their position in the lattice? (because I can permute colors, of course I understand that color *per se* are of no significance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say two excited states contain the same topological excitation if there is a local operator that takes one to the other.

Looking at Fig. 1 in the paper, applying a single Majorana operator $\gamma_i$ to the ground state creates three excitations surrounding site $i$, which has been labelled $A,B,C$ in the figure. This follows from the (anti-)commutation relations for the Majorana operators. Since these excitations are $Z_2$ objects (the $O_i$ have eigenvalues $\pm 1$), applying $\gamma_i \gamma_j$ where $i,j$ are nearest neighbors excites two of the same colored plaquettes (say blue), and cancels out the red and green plaquette excitations. Because of the $Z_2$ nature of the excitations, the previous operator is also equivalent to hopping an excitation from one blue plaquette to the other blue plaquette, i.e. two blue excitations are connected via a local operator but a blue and red plaquette excitation cannot be connected.

You can keep connecting plaquettes of the same color this way to create the string operator that hops these excitations, shown in Fig. 2.

Comment: Thank you for answering, what would be the motivation or reason for considering two topological excitations equivalent if they can be connected by a local operator?

Comment: That's a good question. In topologically ordered systems, we say an excitation is topological when there is no local operator that can create that excitation. This means that we need a non-local operator to take a single topological excitation to the ground state.

A natural extension of this idea tells you that if two excited states are connected by a local operator, you must think of them as the same topological excitation. The idea is that if you want to go to a different topological excitation, you are forced to do something non-local.

Comment: For topological phases with only abelian anyons (which includes the above model), the excitations form a group under "fusion", which just means putting two anyons together and applying any local operator to them. Stated using that language, we say "blue plaquette" x "blue plaquette" = "trivial" under the group multiplication induced by fusion. It is a good exercise to identify the 4 topological sectors / excitations of this model (including the trivial ground state) and determining the complete fusion rules.

Comment: Your comments are really clarifying, thank you. It's very interesting that one can package the "excitations content information" in an algebraic object, like a group. In presence of non-abelian anyons the object would be something like a fusion cateory? can you refer to me any review  articles on this subjects?

Comment: I’m not an expert but yes, that’s the general idea. As you get into more complicated excitations and higher dimensions, you have more data to keep track of which you do using (higher) category theory. If you are mathematically inclined, Appendix E of https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438 gives a good introduction. Xiao-Gang Wen also has a lecture series https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuQW6rVh95ISUMw7eaTVgoGjHbssUbHEw outlining some of the ideas, which I found more physically motivating.